# how to use tiktoken in offline mode computer

Tags: python, tokenize, gpt-3

```
import tiktoken

tokenizer = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base") tokenizer = tiktoken.encoding_for_model("gpt-3.5-turbo")

text = "Hello, nice to meet you"

tokenizer.encode(text)
```

This keeps showing error called requests.exceptions.SSLError. Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)')) ... like this.

I wanted to run this code to see the number of tokens. But it keeps showing error as I mentioned earlier. What am I missing for the code?

Comment: Finally I solved this problem, I entered this line in cmd:
python -m pip install python-certifi-win32
And just solved

Answer (score 17):

## TL;DR for updated tiktoken & cl100k_base

Should work as of time of writing

1. [Download this file](https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken) on your local machine
2. Rename it to `9b5ad71b2ce5302211f9c61530b329a4922fc6a4`
3. Transfer to your remote machine in a folder called "tiktoken_cache"
4. Run the following code every time you need to use tiktoken

```py
import os

tiktoken_cache_dir = "path_to_tiktoken_cache_folder"
os.environ["TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR"] = tiktoken_cache_dir

# validate
assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(tiktoken_cache_dir,"9b5ad71b2ce5302211f9c61530b329a4922fc6a4"))
```

Just ran into this issue today as well. Not the exact same error, but solution for running this offline should be the same. We'll download the necessary file, then "trick" tiktoken into caching it.

This method works if, say you have a remote machine with no internet access and a local machine with internet.

I'm outlining a generalized version below, but you can skip to the tl;dr if you have an updated version of tiktoken and are using the `cl100k_base` tokenizer.

## Generalized Steps

### Step 1: Getting the blob URL

First, let's grab the tokenizer blob URL from the source on your remote machine. If we trace the `get_encoding` function, we find it calls a function from `tiktoken_ext.openai_public` which has the blob URIs for each encoder. Identify the correct function, then print the source

```py
import tiktoken_ext.openai_public
import inspect

print(dir(tiktoken_ext.openai_public))
# The encoder we want is cl100k_base, we see this as a possible function

print(inspect.getsource(tiktoken_ext.openai_public.cl100k_base))
# The URL should be in the 'load_tiktoken_bpe function call'
```

As of time of writing, it should be https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken for cl100k_base

### Step 2: Downloading

Now, navigate to the blob URL on your local machine to download it.

Note: for old versions of tiktoken, Step 1 would have yielded you an Azure blob URI (like `az://openaipublic/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken`); if this is the case, head to the latest source [here](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/blob/main/tiktoken_ext/openai_public.py) and grab a non-azure link for downloading purposes only.

### Step 3: Copy and rename file

Now, transfer the file to your remote machine to a new folder. Tracing the get_encoding function further reveals a call to [`tiktoken.load.read_file_cached()`](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/blob/f19feecd071e22e02bf567ed12ccf161ce6db661/tiktoken/load.py#L29) which indicates the file needs to be renamed. To get the name for the file, run the following code (pulled from source):

```py
import hashlib

blobpath = "your_blob_url_here"
cache_key = hashlib.sha1(blobpath.encode()).hexdigest()
print(cache_key)
```

**Note:** `blobpath` is the blob URL/URI discovered in Step 1; if Step 1 had an `az://` path, you are still using that one.

Rename the file on remote to the cache_key

### Step 4: Set up the tiktoken cache

The `read_file_cached` function then checks environment variables for a cache path and reads from there, so lets set that up:

```py
import os

tiktoken_cache_dir = "path_to_folder_containing_tiktoken_file"
os.environ["TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR"] = tiktoken_cache_dir

# validate
assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(tiktoken_cache_dir, cache_key))
```

**Note:** this is not the full path to the tiktoken file, only the path to the folder containing  the file

This code snippet will need to be run every time you need tiktoken.

### Step 5: Use tiktoken

Congrats, now you can use tiktoken

```py
encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")
encoding.encode("Hello, world")
```

Comment: I solved the error just before saw your answer, thank you so much though!

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this in a Docker container so I'm caching the file when the image is build via CI/CD like so:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Cache the tiktoken encoding file
RUN python -c "import tiktoken; tiktoken.encoding_for_model('gpt-3.5-turbo')"

...
```

Comment: This is a good answer but if you add `ENV TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR /opt/tiktoken_cache/` then you'll be able to see that the file was in fact cached in that directory. I did this to confirm that the cache was doing what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to cache tiktoken during the build of the Docker container is to download and rename it using SHA1 in Dockerfile:

```bash
...
RUN mkdir /opt/tiktoken_cache
ARG TIKTOKEN_URL="https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken"
RUN wget -O /opt/tiktoken_cache/$(echo -n $TIKTOKEN_URL | sha1sum | head -c 40) $TIKTOKEN_URL

ENV TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR=/opt/tiktoken_cache
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment 1

```
import tiktoken_ext.openai_public
import pickle
tiktoken_gpt2 = tiktoken_ext.openai_public.gpt2() # this is a serializable dict
with open('tiktoken_gpt2.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(tiktoken_gpt2, f)
```

Environment 2

```
import tiktoken
import pickle
with open('../tiktoken_gpt2.pkl', 'rb') as f:
     tiktoken_gpt2 = pickle.load(f)
gpt2 = tiktoken.core.Encoding(tiktoken_gpt2.pop('name'), **tiktoken_gpt2)
```